# JSON Schema, oneOf and additionalProperties confusion

Tags: json, jsonschema

I cannot come up with a proper schema for a simple thing.

It should accept objects like:

```
{ "title": "Foo", "type": "type1" }
{ "title": "Foo", "type": "type2" }
```

and should reject likes:

```
{ "title": "Foo", "type": "type1", "extraProp": "bah" }  // extra prop (*) 
{ "title": "Foo", "type": "type3" }                      // wrong "type"
{ "title": "Foo" }                                       // missed "type"
```

This is my schema:

```json
{
  "$id": "foo.schema.json",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/Common"
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Type1"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Type2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$defs": {
    "Common": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": true
    },
    "Type1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "type1"
        }
      },
      "required": [ "type" ],
      "additionalProperties": true
    },
    "Type2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "type2"
        }
      },
      "required": [ "type" ],
      "additionalProperties": true
    }
  }
}
```

Sandbox: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/jQwIwmgO

The problem is that it also allows for (*), i.e. extra props.

How to correct this schema to achieve all three goals?

Note 1: An obvious idea to constrain objects with `additionalProperties = false` makes the whole thing wrong.

Note 2: The `type` property here is a discriminator and `Type1` and `Type2` objects will be populated with their specific props. F.e. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/PQ4cx3Gb

Comment: When you say it is a discriminator do you mean like OpenAPI's `discriminator` keyword, where it actually doesn't affect validation, or do you mean a real discriminator where you use `if` and `then` to check your `type` before applying the schema. The `additionalProperties` keyword doesn't work across an applicator like `allOf` or `oneOf` and you would typically use the `unevaluatedProperties` but that tends to generate rather hard to interpret error messages when there are failures as it drops all the evaluated properties that have failed as well.

Comment: I'm building a schema to validate manually edited YAML files in WebStorm. When I said discriminator, I was referring more the TypeScript discriminated unions to relate the idea. As for `unevaluatedProperties` - I didn't use them before, thanks for mentioning, I'll  read about them.

Comment: @guest I read what I could find so far about `unevaluatedProperties`, but still I cannot get it working. If I add `unevaluatedProperties: false` next to the `oneOf`, it breaks my successful evaluatees: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/lrXrryGr
How to use it properely?

Comment: @guest Ah, seems like I should have added it to the top level: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/4zySYezO 
I can't believe it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Given your clarified requirements this should be what you are looking for. Actual discriminators are implemented using `if`/`then`/`else`. Since you want to have common properties you will then need to use `unevaluatedProperties`. The `additionalProperties` keyword cannot see inside subschemas in applicators like `allOf` or `oneOf`.

The following schema will meet your requirements

```json
{
  "$id": "foo.schema.json",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/Common"
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Type1"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Type2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "unevaluatedProperties": false,
  "$defs": {
    "Common": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Type1": {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "type1"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "type"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "type1prop1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type1prop2": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "else": false
    },
    "Type2": {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "type2"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "type"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "type2prop1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type2prop2": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "else": false
    }
  }
}
```

Sandbox: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/pDGHFlrR

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I should have made it more clear, but I need the `type` property to extend the objects (Type1 and Type2) further, e.g,: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/PQ4cx3Gb

Comment: I updated the original question by adding `Note 2`.